# PoA Clique Ethereum Block Gas Limit relevance

Tags: blockchain, ethereum, consensus, clique

I am running some tests on a private Ethereum network with the Clique consensus engine (Proof of Authority).

I came across issues with the amount of transactions processed per block (or per second - as they can be exchangeable on the Clique context).

I notice, though, that if I reduce the block frequency (let us say to 1 second) and set the gas limit to a tremendously high number (let us say 10 MM), I will be able to fit *a lot of* transactions per block.

There is my question there: there must have some drawback on this rationale. I suppose the processing speed (of the authority nodes) and the network latency (to propagate and synchronise the blocks throughout all the nodes) are two crucial—that is if they are any really. Am I right? What would be the other bottlenecks?

Cheers,